# Ember - Display list when all requests are resolved

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have nested resources which I get to by using forEach loop and promises. Once I get to the objects, I'm after, I do pushObjects to put the objects into one array. The problem I'm having is - I would like to console.log/set the list once ALL the requests are complete. So technically the list would appear  once and not when each individual request is complete.

I have created this JSBin to demonstrate: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/teboli/1/edit?js,output

Answer (score 0):

There are many way but at instant you can use

[beginPropertyChanges](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Observable.html#method_beginPropertyChanges) and [endPropertyChanges](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Observable.html#method_endPropertyChanges)

But a better solution is hidden in your API.

Did you see how many call this process going to take once you have a few items in database? (a lot , at least first time)

Why don't you being all data together using embedded records or [side loading](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_sideloaded-relationships)